# Multiprocessing ou Multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Boas pessoal, recomendam o que para optimizar o codigo? multiprocessing ou multithreading? o script esta a correr em serie, mas tem varios for em serie.

Codigo completo: https://pastebin.com/WtD6XbVT

Comment: O que o código faz? Qual é o problema de otimização dele? Onde está o "gargalo"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeira vez que eu vou dar um pitaco nesse tipo de assunto. Com base nessa [palestra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SSYhuk5hmc) da pycon desse ano, me parece que o seu problema é mais adequado para manipulação e checagem de `str`.
Como é uma atividade que requer mais processamento do que espera de I/O (tirando a parte de relação com BD), **multiprocessing** faz mais sentido.

Mas como li o código muito rápido, pode ser que a extração dos dados (SQL puxa com base em views pesadas, ou algo similias) seja o que consome mais tempo, o que indicaria **multithreading** mas não parece o caso.

**PS**: dá para o código ficar mais pythonico e lean viu, mas vc não perguntou sobre isso ^_^.

Comment: Boas, primeiro de tudo obrigado e segundo não percebi o que quis dizer com "dá para o código ficar mais pythonico e lean viu".